# AWS JSON example using AWS Android SDK

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm looking for a simple AWS example that shows how you can make an API call to my ASP.NET Web API service hosted in Beanstalk, get JSON and parse it AWS Android SDK. I found several but they are specific to IOT or Cognito and do not show parsing. My service is in Beanstalk so it doesn't really matter as it will be just an API call being made. I will look into Cognito once I see parsing in action. Examples I find seem to be tied to other services from AWS that I'm not interested in, like IOT or Lambda.

I don't even know if Amazon SDK offers parsing - that is actually what I'm trying to find out. I hope it does as I do not want to have to manually parse every object.

New to AWS and exploring the innumerable services AWS provides and trying to find out the minimum I need to create an app.

Comment: Are you asking about calling the AWS API via Android? Or are you calling your own service you have built on Elastic Beanstalk? Your question is a bit unclear.

Comment: Thanks @Mark. I'm asking about calling my own ASP.NET Web API service hosted in Beanstalk using AWS Android SDK from an Android app (so I could take advantage of parsing-help, if there is any)

Comment: You would only use the Android AWS SDK to access the AWS API. For example if you wanted to upload a file to S3 or create a new EC2 server, that's what the AWS SDK is for. You can not use the AWS SDK to call your ASP.NET Web API.

Comment: I was comparing it to Azure SDK which I believe provided API in Android to make calls to the web service - like shown in their To do list example. So I would still need the AWS Android SDK if I'm using Cognito. Thank you @MarkB - that's why I wasn't finding anything. Should I delete this question?

Answer (score 0):

You can check one of the solution for calling API:

```
private AmazonCloudWatchClient client(final String awsAccessKey, final String awsSecretKey) {
        final AmazonCloudWatchClient client = new AmazonCloudWatchClient(new BasicAWSCredentials(awsAccessKey, awsSecretKey));
        client.setEndpoint("http://monitoring.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com");
        return client;
    }

    private GetMetricStatisticsRequest request(final String instanceId, String metricName) {
        final long twentyFourHrs = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24;
        final int oneHour = 60 * 60;
        return new GetMetricStatisticsRequest().withStartTime(new Date(new Date().getTime() - twentyFourHrs)).withNamespace("AWS/EC2").withPeriod(oneHour)
                .withDimensions(new Dimension().withName("InstanceId").withValue(instanceId)).withMetricName(metricName).withStatistics("Average", "Maximum")
                .withEndTime(new Date());
    }

    private GetMetricStatisticsResult result(final AmazonCloudWatchClient client, final GetMetricStatisticsRequest awsRequest) {
        return client.getMetricStatistics(awsRequest);
    }

    private void toStdOut(final GetMetricStatisticsResult result, final String instanceId) {
        System.out.println(result); // outputs empty result: {Label:
                                    // CPUUtilization,Datapoints: []}
        System.out.println(result.getDatapoints().size() + "SIZE!!!");
        for (final Datapoint dataPoint : result.getDatapoints()) {
            System.out.println("!!!!");
            System.out.printf("%s instance's average CPU utilization : %s%n", instanceId, dataPoint.getAverage());
            System.out.printf("%s instance's max CPU utilization : %s%n", instanceId, dataPoint.getMaximum());
        }
    }
```

If you will be more precise, I can help you more.